# What type of blinds are these?

Tags: blinds

We are living in a rentl property and there are some blinds in the windows that I would like to replace for the time we are here. They are roman blinds that have a bar along the top and are just clipped into a metal clip attached to the top of the window frame. I can easily unclip them and in theory should be able to buy some new blinds to clip back into their place. But I don't know how to find this type of blind, what to enter into a Google search. Can anyone help?

Comment: Impossible to guess without a photo or sketch...

Comment: I'm not sure a photo would really help. I think most brackets are specific to the manufacturer and product line. You might get lucky taking one to a local store but I think you will get better results by just replacing the whole thing, as @ilikedirt says.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless, it's unlikely you'll be able to clip the new blinds into the clips for the roman shades you want to remove. Luckily, the clips are probably easily removed with a screwdriver, and you can just attach the new blinds with their own clips the same way. When you move out, take the new blinds off, patch the screw holes with spackle, and put the original roman shades back on.

Answer (score 1):

Unclip then and take them to a local home improvement store.  The sales clerks can point you to the products they sell and offer advise on your particular style.
When searching on google (and presumably buying online) you run the risk of buying something that isn't the right size or doesn't fit, and they may not be returnable.  With home improvement store items, you can easily return them if they don't work out.